# UWP app submission fails because of Keyword length

Tags: uwp, azure-devops, windows-store, submission

I'm getting this error while uploading a package to the store (not a flight) with Azure DevOps using the [Windows Store extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-RDX-MRO.windows-store-publish).

`[error]Status 400: {"code":"InvalidParameterValue","data":[],"details":[],"message":"The length of Keyword must be 30 or less","source":"Ingestion Api","target":"keyword"}`

I only get the error if I am uploading a package that already exists in a flight.  I can't find any info about "Keywords" in the submission. If I go to the submission in the dashboard, I can publish the submission.

Comment: Hi, I'm experiencing exactly the same issue, did you manage to understand the problem? thanks

Comment: No, I'm not sure what to do. Each search term is not longer than the expected length.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if its' related, but I reduced in the partner center/app/store listing the characters in **product features** and in **search terms** to less than 30 characters, and it worked

Comment: But each of my search terms are not longer than the expected length.

Comment: Are they shorter than 30 characters? (I know that partner center allow longer ones)

Comment: Whaaat. I do have one that is 34. But the partner center allows it! I'll try it on our next release.